# How to add html classes to I18n locale links in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am trying to add html classes to the I18n language links in Rails for but it seems that Rails just ignores it.

```
<li class="lang-menu"><%= link_to_unless_current "", locale: "en", class: 'english language' %></li>
<li class="lang-menu"><%= link_to_unless_current "", locale: "it", class: 'italian language' %></li>
<li class="lang-menu"><%= link_to_unless_current "", locale: "rus", class: 'russian language' %></li>
```

When I do inspect element in my browser I just get a plain link without any class:

```
<li class="lang-menu"><a href="/it?class=italian+language"></a></li>
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use explicit hashes: `<%= link_to_unless_current "", { locale: "en"}, {class: 'english language'} %>`

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "", locale: "it", {class: 'italian language'} %>
```

Comment: sorry i meant to add hashes

    <%= link_to_unless_current "", locale: "it", {class: 'italian language'} %>

did not write the whole line thought you would know it is to be added.